# string element of array is not able to access after json decode

Tags: json, decode

this is my code for decode array

`$transfer = '{"type": "BALANCE","status": "REJECTED"}'; $json = json_decode($transfer); echo $json->status;`

it is not displaying status value.

if I change status to integer value.

$transfer = '{"type": "BALANCE","status": "1234"}';

then it is displaying status value as 1234.

how to display status value if its in string format.

Answer (score 1):

This is working fine

```php
<?php 

$transfer = '{"type": "BALANCE","status": "REJECTED"}'; 
$json = json_decode($transfer); 
echo $json->status; //displays REJECTED

?>
```

Comment: it is not returning anything.. I don't understand the problem..

Comment: `echo $json->status` is displaying REJECTED at my end.

Comment: Add your code https://www.w3schools.com/php/phptryit.asp?filename=tryphp_compiler between <?php ?> tags and see result

Comment: I have tried all those things.. it is working fine out of the project.. this transfer data I am getting is from wise transfer api.. I am confused weather that data format is wrong or what else?

Comment: If you are getting data from api. Try `JSON.stringify($transfer)` before json decode.